# Convert a tf-idf matrix in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python

I have the following dataset:

```
test_set = ("The sun in the sky", "The sun in the light", "Do not blame it on moonlight", "Do not blame it on sunshine")
```

Now I use the following code to create a tf-idf matrix

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
vectorizer.fit_transform(test_set)

smatrix = vectorizer.transform(test_set)
smatrix.todense()

tfidf = TfidfTransformer(norm="l2")
tfidf.fit(smatrix)
tf_idf_matrix = tfidf.transform(smatrix)
```

What I would like to do now is to 'feed' this matrix to a knn cluster algorithm.
So for example like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[0.2, 0.3, 0.4], [0.2, 0.3, 0.41], [0.2, 0.1, 0.05], [0.1, 0.1, 0.08]], columns=('column1', 'column2', 'column3'))

k_means = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=2) 
k_means.fit(df)
print(k_means.labels_)
```

I cant seem to convert the matrix into a df however. If I do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(tf_idf_matrix)
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/marcvanderpeet/PycharmProjects/untitled/test.py", line 47, in <module>
df = pd.DataFrame(tf_idf_matrix)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 345, in __init__
raise PandasError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')
```

pandas.core.common.PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Any thoughts on how I can convert this?

Comment: Have you imported any other module and named it `pd`, by chance?

Comment: No, just pandas

Comment: `pd.DataFrame` not `pd.Dataframe`.

Comment: @Psidom: Good catch!

Comment: @Psidom, thanks! Devil is in the details. Got another error now however... (see edit) any thoughts

Comment: What is `tf_idf_matrix` here? Is it a numpy array?

Answer (score 3):

`tf_idf_matrix` has a type `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix`. You can check this by typing `type(tf_idf_matrix)`. In pandas documentation for pd.DataFrame class we can see, that it's possible to get an instance of the class passing only numpy ndarray (structured or homogeneous), dict, or DataFrame. To convert `tf_idf_matrix` to numpy representation you can do following: `tf_idf_matrix = tf_idf_matrix.todense()`. This line can transform `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix` to `numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix` and pd.DataFrame can work with data of this type. After that you can get `df` and pass it to `k_means.fit()` method.

Answer (score 2):

Note that since version 0.20 you can directly use scipy sparse matrices to create a pandas SparseDataFrame :

```
sp_arr = csr_matrix(arr)
sdf = pd.SparseDataFrame(sp_arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

We Can also Use Sklearn Pipeline

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer   
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

test_set = ["The sun in the sky", "The sun in the light", "Do not blame it on 
           moonlight", "Do not blame it on sunshine"]

df = pd.DataFrame(test_set, columns =['sent'])
print(df)
                           sent
0            The sun in the sky
1          The sun in the light
2  Do not blame it on moonlight
3  Do not blame it on sunshine

model =  Pipeline([('vectorizer',CountVectorizer()), ('tf_trans',TfidfTransformer()),('k_means', KMeans(n_clusters=2))])


# and now we can just data directly pass the data to the model
model.fit(df)




# Now if we want to predict new comment we have to just pass
print(model.predict(['enjoy sunshine ']))
o/p-->array([0])
```